# GraphQL Server Placement with Drupal

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I was wondering if there was a best practice for architecting a GraphQL server in relation to a React frontend and Drupal backend. Currently I have setup GraphQL with Express on the React side of things, which in turn makes REST requests to the Drupal 8 REST API in the GraphQL resolvers.

Would it be better to place the GraphQL server on the Drupal side of things and forget the REST API altogether?

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: I think either way is fine. Obviously if the REST api never gets used outside of graphql requests then it's kind of pointless, but if it's not causing trouble then whatever

Comment: Would it be ideal for performance? What would be a better pipeline? Open to trying new things.

Comment: Having a separate service, like you have, to extend a REST api with graphql is very common. I wouldn't worry too much about the performance related to that unless its noticeably bad. you can add things like dataloader to make fewer requests. to give you a more specific answer you'd have to talk about which drupal features you are actually using. maybe scrapping drupal alltogether would make more sense, but again I wouldn't worry too much about that part.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @azium! Free's me up to focus on more important things in the pipeline.

Comment: Oh one last question. Is it better to say, return an array from a REST server that contains all of the entity dependencies inside that one request. For example if I request a piece of Content that also has a User entity inside it, would it be better to return that Content with the full user inside of it, or let GraphQL separately make a query for that in the User resolver? Does that make any sense?